# Нужно чтобы код срабатывал для всех страниц сайта, кроме главной

Tags: php

У меня есть кусок кода в header, который на мобильном отключает отображение блока в результатах поиска.

```
 <? if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/search/') !== false) { ?>
            <style>
            @media (max-width: 800px) {
                .prew {
                    display: none;
                }
            }
            </style>
        <?}?>
```

Но мне нужно еще сделать отключение блока НА ВСЕХ страницах, КРОМЕ ГЛАВНОЙ

```
<? if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/') !== false) { ?>
{
выполняем действие
}
<?}?>
```

Сейчас срабатывает для всех страниц, включая главную :(

Помогите, пожалуйста, советом!

Comment: `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != '/') ...`

Comment: К сожалению, так же применяет ко всем страницам и к главной... :(

Comment: А зачем вы прячете медиа запросы?!

Comment: У вас заглавная страница не index.php случаем? И проверять надо  != 'index.php'

Comment: Вы хоть расскажите на чем сайт построен, если самописка, то используются ли разные шаблоны для страниц

Comment: Сайт на 1C-Bitrix. Главная не index.php, я полагаю...

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
if (parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH) == '/') {
    // это главная страница
}
```

Comment: Не получилось. Всё вставил правильно. Эта строка так же применяет это ко всем страницам и к главной в том числе...

Comment: что у вас выдает `var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);` на главной и на остальных страницах?

Comment: string(188) "/?back_url_admin=%2Fbitrix%2Fadmin%2Ffileman_file_edit.php%3Fpath%3D%252Fbitrix%252Ftemplates%252Fclaude%252Fheader.php%26full_src%3DY%26site%3Ds15%26lang%3Dru%26filter%3DY%26set_filter%3DY"

Только это, как ни странно...

Comment: исправил ответ, попробуйте еще так

Answer (score 0):

```
$pages=array('/');
if(!in_array($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],$pages)){
// your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?/* Если мы находимся на главной */?>
<? if ($APPLICATION->GetCurPage(false) === '/'): ?>
...
<? endif; ?>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо) помогло